# Gunicorn: Failed to activate the service Error

Tags: nginx, server, gunicorn

I'm following this YouTube Tutorial to setup my Server with Flask and Nginx:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2WA-A67Bks&t=360s

Right now I'm at the Gunicorn part. I tried to start following commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl start index

systemctl enable index

systemctl status index
```

But it doesn't work. My index.service file looks like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve One
After=network.target

[Service]
User=daemon
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html
Environment="PATH=/var/www/html/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/html/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can pleace help anyone?